# What is the opposite of "usage"?

Tags: meaning, antonyms

I am looking for a word which meaning is the opposite of "usage". The context is the use of devices of any sort. The best I've come up with so far is to look at the situation from the devices perspective and consider "usage periods" and "inactivity periods".

Comment: The term *usage* is tricky here and is better avoided. *Active-Inactive*, *Up-Down*, *Busy-Idle* and similar pairs would suit the context much better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*[Idle time](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/idle+time)* or *idle periods* could be what you are looking for. The term is already in use in the computer and other industries to denote time when a machine could be working but isn't.

Comment: Yes. I stand by mine as correct, but this is correct and also preferable IMO.

Comment: Indeed `neglect` is probably more correct for the fact that it's a noun and `idle` is an adjective, although the latter seems better suited as its meaning seems more specific to the context I described.

Answer (score 2):

*Neglect* can fit a lot of cases, but has a negative connotation that may be best avoided.

*Inactivity* is indeed a good choice. The related "inactive periods" doesn't match noun-for-noun, but it does match noun-phrase for noun-phrase, and reads more naturally IMO.

*Rest* might also be considered, but it has a positive connotation that might be almost as well avoided as the negative connotations of *neglect*, especially if you want to reduce redundancy by reducing how often the devices are inactive.

Answer (score 0):

*Disregarding*. You could be *using* something while *disregarding* something else.

Comment: This isn't actually the **opposite** of 'usage', as the question asks.  'Disregarding' is the opposite of 'regarding', which isn't synonymous with 'usage'.